# Wordpress YouTheme Logo Link Change

Tags: url, hyperlink

This one little issue is driving me mad and i am hope someone could help

All i need to do is change the home url of the logo to another link

```html
$config = $theme->get('logo', []);
$attrs_link = [];
$attrs_image = [];

// Logo Text
$logo = $config['text'];

// Link
$attrs_link['href'] = $theme->get('site_url');
$attrs_link['class'][] = isset($class) ? $class : '';
$attrs_link['class'][] = 'uk-logo';
```

Comment: Please don't post your code in an image.  Copy and paste it into the body of your question

Comment: i was getting erros trying to post the code...but i posted it now

Comment: @Patrick i suggest you change your attitude... (1) you haven't figured it out either (2) you posted your question 3 hours ago from the time of this comment (3) it's YOOtheme and not YouTheme -- which makes it hard for us to Google (4) WHY do you need to change the home URL??

Comment: can you not change `$attrs_link['href'] = $theme->get('site_url');` to `$attrs_link['href'] = 'http://the-url-you-want';` or `$attrs_link['href'] = your_function_to_change_url();` ?

Comment: aequalsb Your are Brilliant Man! $attrs_link['href'] = 'http://the-url-you-want';   Worked Perfect!